# Angular8 Thermal Printing

Tags: angular, angular8, thermal-printer

I have used https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-thermal-print for integrating the EPSON t82 thermal printer but struggling with printing any image.

```
this.printService.init()
      .setSize('large')
      .setBold(true)
      .writeLine('Hello')
      .setBold(false)
      .flush();
```

This function above simply prints the text but if there anyway I can print any image (QR-Code) using this?

Comment: I don't think it is currently possible. https://github.com/bebo925/ng-thermal-print/issues/13 Please consider creating a pull request if you add this feature.

Comment: It would be great if you can share your code for angular thermal printing. I am unable to connect to printer itself. I am using Epson TM t82.

Comment: Hi, I'd  tried using the documentation to connect to the printer using USB. But, it didn't connected. can u please tell me how to connect to the printer using USB ?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is having a issue, Please add this (It is missing in the documentation).

1. insider file( app.module.ts) add the below.
   import { PrintService} from 'ng-thermal-print';
2. inside the provider add the service (example below)
   providers: [PrintService, { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-IN' }],
3. Follow the remaining steps as in documentation.